Nas storage expansion
I have a server that I use for Minecraft and a shared folder. I would like to know how to turn the rest of the unused hard drives into NAS storage. I have one 14TB drive so far.

You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details; but I'd suggest picking a protocol (SaMBa, NFS etc) and then specifying a directory etc that will be shared on your network.  Then you can amend other machines in your network to take advantage of the shared resource  (how it'll be used will determine what protocols are best suited; from this you can decide software & setup options)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
